# Cannot seem to perform a simple pip install on this package

Tags: git, macos, pip, theano

Currently trying to follow the instructions [here](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_macos.html#bleeding-edge-installation-recommended), in order to install the bleeding edge version of Theano. Now when I invoke a,

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git#egg=Theano
```

I get this on my terminal:

```
zsh: no matches found: git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git#egg=Theano
```

I am not sure as to what I am doing wrong, since this is exactly the instruction that was on the page.

Comment: It seems likely that zsh, unlike sh/bash, gives `#` a special meaning. If so, quoting the `#` should get the command past the shell, so that `pip` can run it.

Comment: @torek That is the answer. If you put it down, I could accept it!

Comment: @torek Or should I delete this question? It's a bit trivial.

Comment: Up to you (I'm not on line that much right now btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh`, which is the shell that I use, currently assigns `#` a special meaning. Thus it would be best to run it under quotation marks. My command is now:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Theano/Theano.git`#`egg=Theano
```